# Get the Signature algorithm from a public key?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

When I do PublicKey.getAlgorithm(), it only returns me RSA. Am looking for something to return Sha1RSA. Basically to identify if it is a sha1 or sha2 algorithm.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This might be more suited for stackoverflow, but without even specifying the language you have very little chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

A key is a key. There is no such thing as a "RSA-with-SHA-1 key". A RSA key that can be used for signatures (using the [PKCS#1 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447)) will be used in conjunction with some other parameters, including a hash function such as SHA-1 and SHA-256; but there is no intrinsic property of a key that would prevent usage of SHA-1 or SHA-256 as hash function within a signature algorithm implementation.

Whether you will use SHA-1 or SHA-256 for your RSA signatures is entirely up to you (or, rather, it should be up to the specification of the protocol you are implementing -- if you are not following a precise specification then there will be much wailing and grinding of teeth).

Comment: Sorry about the language part, it is java.

Here is what I am looking to do, need to validate an incoming request signed. I was looking in trying to get the algorithm programmatically by going through the certificate path, instead of configuring it per request.

Comment: The details of the signature algorithm are not in the certificate. The certificate contains only the public key (so: "RSA"), not any information on any algorithm with which that key has been used.

Answer (score 0):

Apologize for posting a question without doing research on my own.

Here is how i got around just in case anyone gets into the same bind

convert the cert into bytes and then convert to X509Certificate. Then you can do X509Certificate.getSigAlgName();

Thanks Again

Comment: That's the algorithm for the signature *of* the certificate itself. It is not necessarily the algorithm used with the key *in* the cert. E.g. it is possible to have a cert containing an RSA key, which as @Thomas says can be used for sha1-RSA or sha256-RSA or sha3-RSA (when standardized) or even for rsaEncryption (unless retricted by KeyUsage or EncryptedKeyUsage), but the cert itself is signed with perstd-DSA or varies-ECDSA not RSA at all.